# IP Routing on All Switches or just Core

Tags: vlan, ip-routing, hp-procurve

I have 1 core switch in our MDF for server equipment and 6 data closet switches that connect clients.

At this point I only have IP Routing enabled on the core switch so all IP routing is done in one central location in the MDF. We only have 2 VLANs that extend out to the other 6 data closet switches, Data and Voice VLAN.

My question is, should IP Routing be enabled on the other 6 data closet switches as well or is it best practice to do all the IP Routing in one central location like I have it now?

Comment: Can not be answered like this - that may or may not be good, depending what you do. In the standard simple scenarios - no, no need to do routing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the VLANs are trunked to the other closets, you only need `ip routing` on the core switch.